# How to set in-app billing item as used?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

We are writing chat alike app in which user can buy some amount of messages. Let's say 100 messages. We can control within our app how much of those messages user used.

Now imagine user exhausted purchased 100 messages then reinstall app and voi'la - user has again 100 messages!

So the question is: how to control that item is already used? Can I report back to in-app server that purchased item can't be used anymore?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new Market Billing library revision #3 - it's possible to use items consumption

[Proof link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2012/12/in-app-billing-version-3)

Answer (score 0):

Those would be unmanaged items, and by definition you are responsible for managing them. The only reliable way to do this is to do it on your own server and associated items with the some sort of stable user identifier, such as their Google account. If by 'in-app server' you mean Google's servers, they only do this for managed items: they check if you already have the item and you get an error if so.

Comment: I'm talking about managed items. For sure if user bought it - Google's server shows it as available. But imagine user bought 100 messages and already sent 100 messages (in my app I control number of sent messages). Now user reinstalls application completely deleting local database and now when user logs again he/she again has 100 messages. How to handle this kind of hacking?